# Mean Square Convergence with Square Root n Term

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, asymptotics, lp-spaces

If $\sqrt{n}(X_n-X)$ converges in mean squre ($L^2$), do we have $X_n$ converges to $X$ in mean square? How can we show this?

Moreover, Is there a Slutsky Theorem for $L^p$ convergence?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In general if $W_{n}\to W$ in $L^p$ and $Z_{n}\to Z$ in ${L^p}$, then $W_nZ_n\to WZ$ in $L^p$. Indeed, let $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ denote the $L^p$ norm and note the inequality
$$
\lVert W_{n}Z_{n}-WZ\rVert\leq \lVert W_n\rVert\lVert Z_n-Z\rVert+  \lVert Z\rVert \lVert W_n-W\rVert
$$
from which the result follows.

Returning to the original question, suppose
$
\sqrt n(X_n-X)\to U
$
in $L^2$ for some $U$. Because $1/\sqrt{n}\to 0$ in $L^2$, it follows that the product $X_n-X\to 0$ in $L^2$ as desired.